# Button doesn't work after I put them into named functions

Tags: javascript

I write some `JavaScript` code, when I write them in anonymous functions like

`<br />"button.onclick = function() { some code; };`,

It works normally. But when I try to write as

```
<br />
foe.onclick = myFunction();
function myFunction() { same code here; }
```

Then nothing happens when I click the button. I try to add `alert` in `myFunction()` and it appears immediately after the page is load. Why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change from

```
foe.onclick = myFunction();
```

to

```
foe.onclick = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the function call with parentheses, you are calling the function. So, when you use:
`foe.onclick = myFunction();`
It actually executes the function at this point and returns the value for `onclick` to use.
You can also use:

```
function myFunction () {
   return anotherFunction();
}
foe.onclick = myFunction();
```

Here, `anotherFunction` would be called when you click `foe` element.

As Xin points out, you can use:

```
foe.onclick = myFunction;
```

to call `myFunction` on clicking the element. In Javascript, functions can be referenced and passed like variables :D